# Bayesian: Does the choice of the prior on the covariance matrix influence the posterior mean in a gaussian model?

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, normal-distribution

Suppose we have a Multivariate Gaussian model, with some observed data $X$:
$$X \; | \; \mu, \Sigma \sim MultiNormal(\mu, \Sigma)\\
\text{each }\mu_i \sim Normal(\mu_0, \sigma_0)$$
and some prior on $\Sigma$, e.g. Inverse Wishart.

My question is: Does the choice of the prior for $\Sigma$ influence the marginal posterior for $\mu_i | X$?

Intuitively I would say no, or at least not influencing the expected value $\mathbb{E} \; \mu_i | X$, however in [1] the posterior mean is dependent on $\Sigma$. Can you give me a intuitive explanation why?

[1] [Multivariate normal posterior](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/28744/multivariate-normal-posterior)

Comment: Just check any textbook covering this problem.